# how to re-add new div by id in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two divs

```
 <div id="register">

 <div id="login">
```

with a switch button swtchbtn

on page load I removed login using

```
      $('#login').remove();
```

I want to re-add login when the switch button is clicked so I tried this

```
$('#swtchbtn').click(function(){     
     $('#register').remove();
     $('#login').add('div');
});
```

the problem is that login div is not showing. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: You remove `div id=login` then try to add another `div` to the `#login` that you just removed?  Can you not see why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Did you mean to *re-add* the login input?  Something like `$(document).append('<div id="login">');`?

Comment: yes I want to re-add it @freedomn-m

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `.show()` and `.hide()` rather than add/remove DOM nodes.

Comment: i just found out that this will be the better choice, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `$('#login').add('div');` will attempt to add a new div to an existing div with id login.  As you've removed the login div, this code does nothing, instead you should use:

```
$(document).append('<div id="login"></div>');
```

or a parent wrapper rather than `document`.

However, it's highly unlikely that your `login` div is just that (an empty div) and you'll have other code such as name/password inputs, making this process of adding/removing DOM nodes overly complicated.

Instead you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` to switch between them or the more succinct `.toggle()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login").hide(); // or use display:none in the HTML so you don't get FOUC
  $('#switchbtn').click(function() {
    $('#register,#login').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='login' style='display:none;'>login</div>
<div id='register'>register</div>
<button type='button' id='switchbtn'>switch</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add and remove, it might be better to use .show() and .hide(). That way the div is still there, but you can conditionally show or hide the content depending on what the user has clicked i.e.

```
$.(document).ready(function(){
    $('#swtchbtn').click(function(){
        $('#register').hide();
        $('#login').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way

```
$('#swtchbtn').toggle(function(){ 
    $('#register').css("display" ,"block"); 
    $('#login').css('display','none'); 
});
```

the above code have not been tested but believe it should work for you or you could do it without toggling.

```
$('#swtchbtn').click(function(){ 
    $('#register').css("display" ,"none"); 
    $('#login').css('display','block'); 
});
```

Comment: You'll find it easier to use `.show()` and `.hide()` rather than `.css("display", ...`